# Low-level keyboard hook issue : Keyboard state losed when application is not focused (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, keyboard, hook, low-level

I've been asked to develop a new application that will work along side the existing one. Both application will wait for a barcode reader input. I don't want our operator to scan a barcode twice: once for the existing application (16bit - clipper, no sources) and once for the new application. To solves this issue I've decided to use a low-level keyboard hook (written in Delphi). It looks perfect since 2 applications will need the barcode reader input and that my application will not be focused the most of the time.

My low-level keyboard hook is well working when my application is focused. For example, if I enter into a TEdit control and then if I scan my barcode :

- the awaited characters will be
  displayed in the TEdit control
  (#02;90BDIJ#).
- the low-level hook will get all characters (# , then 0, then 2 and so
  on).

Things are getting worse when my application is no more focused : if I open notepad and then if I scan my barcode :

- the awaited characters will be
  displayed in notepad (#02;90BDIJ#).
- the low-level hook will get wrongs characters : "àé;çàbdij"

It looks like the Keyboard state is no taken in account ! It looks like the Shift, Ctrl or even Alt keys are no more taken in account.On my french keyboard :

- '#' = CTRL = ALT + "
- '0' = SHIFT + à
- '2' = SHIFT + é
- ...

Does anyone now how to solve this problem ?
Am I doing it the wrong way (should I use windows messages instead ?). Thank you in advance.

FWIW Here is my source code :

```
unit Unit5;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Math;

const
  LLKHF_UP             =  $0080;

type
  tagKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT =  packed record
    vkCode :            DWORD;
    scanCode :          DWORD;
    flags :             DWORD;
    time :              DWORD;
    dwExtraInfo :       Integer;
  end;
  KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT      =  tagKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;
  PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT     =  ^KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;

var
  hkHook : HHook;
  function LowLevelKeyboardProc(Code, wParam, lParam: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
  procedure HookIt;
  procedure UnHookIt;

implementation

uses Unit1;

procedure HookIt;
begin
  hkHook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL,@LowLevelKeyboardProc,hInstance,0);
end;

procedure UnHookIt;
begin
  UnHookWindowsHookEx(hkHook);
end;

function LowLevelKeyboardProc(Code, wParam, lParam: Integer): Integer;
var
  KeyState : TKeyboardState;
  NewChar: array[0..1] of Char;
  Hook : PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;
  bControlKeyDown : Boolean;
begin
  Try
    Hook := Pointer(lParam);
    Case Code Of
      HC_ACTION:
        begin
            If (Hook^.flags And LLKHF_UP) <> 0 Then
            begin
              FillChar(NewChar,2,#0);
              GetKeyboardState(KeyState);
              If ToAscii(Hook^.vkCode,Hook^.scanCode,KeyState,NewChar,0) = 1 Then
                    Form1.ListBox1.Items.Add(NewChar[0]);
            end;
        end;boar
      end;
  Finally
     Result := CallNextHookEx(hkHook,Code,wParam,lParam);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: The barcode readers that I've used emulate a keyboard so there's no need to write any code. Are you using a reader that doesn't have this capability?

Comment: My barcode reader also emulate a keyboard. Barcode reader input is currently processed by a existing (16 bit / clipper) software. I've been asked to develop a new application that will work along side the old one. I want to use low-lvel keyboard hook so that our operator will not have to scan the barcode twice (one for the clipper software and one for our future inhouse software)

Comment: It is a mistake to pack this record. Don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a local keyboard hook.  You need to create a [global hook](http://web.archive.org/web/20090213112308/http://delphi.about.com/od/kbwinshell/a/delphi_hook.htm) for it to work everywhere.  Global keyboard (and mouse) hooks need to be implemented in a separate .dll.

**Update:**

I have been corrected.  Apparently this does not need to be implemented in a dll.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Bruce but I wasn't able to make it works under Windows 7 & Delphi (unicode world ;).

Comment: I've done this in Delphi 2007 in Vista with great success - but yes unicode might get in your way.  I think Bruce is correct and a global hook is your only option.

Comment: Alister, I'm trying to adapt this code into a DLL... So far no luck, I can't even get a key stroke :(
Would you mind to help me on this ?

Comment: @Bruce Low-level keyboard hook is called in the context of the thread that installed the hook. It does not require a DLL.

Comment: Link is dead (redirects to a unrelated topic).

Comment: Updated the link using the Wayback machine.

Answer (score 3):

i encountered this issue today and was resolved by adding these lines after GetKeyboardState(KeyState);

```
KeyState[VK_CAPITAL] := GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL);
KeyState[VK_SHIFT] := GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT);
KeyState[VK_CONTROL] := GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL);
KeyState[VK_MENU] := GetKeyState(VK_MENU);
```

Comment: Incredibly, this worked for me. I had just assumed that GetKeyState was simply a way to look at a specific index of the array returned by GetKeyboardState. However, this appears not to be the case based on your answer. Would you happen to know why this approach works?